# What library/fitting algorithm for C++ do I need to fit an 1D function to experimental data?

Tags: python, c++, c, simulation

I am programming a physics simulation (Ising model, if it matters) and I need to fit an 1D decaying exponential function to a set of data and have an estimation of the parameters of the function but however I have searched I cannot for the life of me understand the different fitting methods and choose one that can accomplish this seemingly non-complex task. I have a program in Python that uses scipy.optimization.curve_fit for this function but due to the simulation requiring enormous computing time I am trying to switch to C++.

Answer (score 3):

[`scipy.optimize.curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) uses the `lm` method by default for unconstrained problems. The documentation for [`scipy.optimize.least_squares`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html) says that

> Method ‘lm’ (Levenberg-Marquardt) calls a wrapper over least-squares algorithms implemented in MINPACK (lmder, lmdif).

MINPACK is a Fortran library, but there seems to be a C/C++ version as well: [C/C++ Minpack](https://devernay.github.io/cminpack/).

Then there are some projects mentioned in the [Eigen documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page#Projects_using_Eigen), foremost the [Ceres Solver](http://ceres-solver.org/).

If C is an option, the GNU Scientific Library (GSL) provides [linear](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/lls.html) and [non-linear](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/nls.html) least squares functionality.